# Sending request with PHP witout getting response

Tags: php, performance, curl

Maybe this is a simple question, but I didn't find answer in web.

I have remote script that works when I'm opening

```
http://www.example.com/do_it.php
```

I can't include it, cause this page can give fatal errors, can take too long to load.

I need to load that page from php in the fastest and the easyest way.

Now I'm doing

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,$withReturn);
$execute = curl_exec($ch);
```

But this script get response, so consequently it will take more time than script that returns only headers, or not returns anything.

That is the better way to do it?

If it will help `do_it.php` is in same server from where I need to call it.

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Seems like you already have a working solution?

Comment: Yes it's working, but I'm worryng about performance. I really hope that exists better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the possible solutions for executing the request and not waiting for a response would be to use php.net/curl_multi_exec and then avoid parsing the response. Another approach would be to use sockets, open a connection to the script, write the request then close the connection without readying the response.

A example curl script:
https://github.com/vrana/php-async/blob/master/CurlAsync.php

An example usage of the socket method:

```
$fp = fsockopen('example.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

$out = "GET /do_it.php HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$out.= "Host: example.com\r\n";
$out.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

fwrite($fp, $out);
fclose($fp);
```

Above example is untested and is provided as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Need to check how fast `fsockopen` works, but logically it's exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

Well the fastest way would be to check all of the methods. There is

CURL    - curl_exec()

Sockets - fsockopen()

And if you just want to download the response of that do_it.php page, then use get_file_contents().

Comment: As I know `get_file_contents()` is the slowest method to get response, but in my case I don't need response at all, so I'm seraching for method that will not even try to get response.